# Llenar y autocompletar datos en campo creado

Tags: trigger, sql-server-2012, concat

solicito su orientación con el siguiente problema que tengo. Poseo una tabla con mas de 25 mil registros en la cual cree un campo en el cual quiero concatenar 2 campos ya existentes. Ahora necesito realizar 2 acciones:

La primera es poder realizar una actualización masiva para poder llenar el campo que cree y la segunda es crear un Trigger para poder hacer que ese campo se llene automaticamente.

Los datos que tengo son los siguientes:

Table direcciones
Address nvarchar
CardCode    nvarchar
Street  nvarchar
City    nvarchar
LineNum int
ID_APP  varchar

Tengo los siguientes datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que el campo ID_APP tenga los datos de los campos CardCode y LineNum con la siguiente estructura de ejemplo "10462606-00", "10462606-01", etc.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.